# Filter by text in Access 2016 Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2016

I have a 3,521,117 rows of data of date that is in text format (ex. 2016-03-04).
I want to make a Query in access but with just the info from 2017 and after to reduce the quantity of data.

I have tried with this sql code:

```
SELECT [Ventas].[Fecha]
FROM [Ventas]
WHERE [Ventas].[Fecha] LIKE '%2017%' OR [Ventas].[Fecha] LIKE '%2018%'
```

But I don't get any kind of info but a blank sheet

The only one that I have been able to make work is:

```
SELECT [Ventas].[Fecha]
FROM [Ventas]
WHERE [Ventas].[Fecha] LIKE '2017-01-01' OR [Ventas].[Fecha] LIKE '2017-01-02'
```

But probably is not the best way to input like that the 365 days of the year

Is there some way to Delete the data from 2014 to 2016, or just get in the query from 2017 and after.

I cannot use betweendates because its text and cannot convert it from the source table.

Comment: Are you using sql server or access? And why are you storing dates as strings??? The date/datetime datatype exist for storing dates.

Comment: The 3 millions is just the number of rows I have in the access worksheet, and I am trying to make a Query from Access to get less information because of size limits of some files I have.
I want to have another table but with just the data from 2017
I hope I explained my self english not my first language

Comment: So this is Access and not sql server? Removing the sql server tag as they are not the same thing.

Comment: @JuaBar Does MS Access has WorkSheets? I think MS Excel has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about access but this is sql server which you tagged.

```
SELECT [Tabla: Ventas].[Fecha]
FROM [Tabla: Ventas]
WHERE [Tabla: Ventas].[Fecha]>='20170101'
```

and if fecha is not a date then cast it as one

```
cast(fecha as date) >= '20170101'
```

Comment: if the speed is insufficient, you can add an index to fecha